# Function inside of an echo (PHP)

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have created a function which returns information about a website, based on an array function. The function works like this:

```
site_info('sitename');
```

Which returns:

```
Example Site Name
```

Using a code similar to this:

```
 function site_info($info) {
     $array = array('sitename' => 'Example Site Name');
     echo $array[$info];
 }
```

I wish to print these unformatted and then format them after, for example:

```
echo '<title>'.site_info('sitename').'</title>';
```

However, this prints into:

```
Example Site Name <title></title>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening? One idea I had was that perhaps because the function is echoing the output, which is then inside of another input it wasn't liking it- if this is the case, is there a work around?

Comment: Because you don't **return** anything from your function. You print it in the function itself, so the function gets called, before `echo`. Just **return** the value and everything works

Comment: replace `echo $array[$info];` with `return $array[$info];`

Comment: `$array = array('sitename' => 'Example Site Name);` see anything there? you're missing a `'`, it should be `$array = array('sitename' => 'Example Site Name');`. Also, you should **return** that, despite echo may work too. Also, another error there: `echo '<title>'.site_info('sitename').'</title>;`... still missing the last `'`'. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9bc2af9f9702fbc1409ca70aa4880ada6cfccbe9 That's just it anyway.

Comment: Error inside of the array wasn't actually in my code, due to it being an error- but edited for clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use return inside function instead of eacho and make sure you are using correct array key like:

```
 function site_info($info) {
     $array = array('sitename' => 'Example Site Name');
     return $array['sitename']; // in your case there will be $info as key
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to `return` the value from the function -

```
 function site_info($info) {
     $array = array('sitename' => 'Example Site Name'); // ' was missing
     return $array[$info];
 }
```

And then call the function in `echo` -

```
echo '<title>' . site_info('sitename') . '</title>'; // ' was missing
```

Comment: Your code still has syntax errors in it! Oh and I wonder from where you got this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30801206/function-inside-of-an-echo-php#comment49650671_30801206

Comment: Appreciated @ShaifulIslam. This kind of people exists. :)

Comment: @b0s3 I like this guy because I saw him active most of time but did not expected such comment and down-vote from him.

Comment: you should notice the OP that also this line is wrong: `echo '<title>'.site_info('sitename').'</title>;`, else fixing the above won't be enough and he still will be experiencing a parse error, because of another missing `'` :P

Comment: @b0s3: Didn't see that,was that already there? a few minutes ago the only available part was another, but I see "edited 13 mins ago", so it's probably my browser's fail, sorry :P just wanted to point that out in any case, because the OP may not notice that immediatly (else he would have fixed that earlier, no?)